# Where can I find the value of this seemingly rare MEGA BLOKS tree and whether there are additional parts?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

[image]I am looking for a value on this MEGA BLOKS item and whether there are additional parts to it.  I have searched AM05829 AND AMO5829 on internet, ebay, and etsy and have found nothing.  I seem to be able to attach only one photo, but the previous item # is stamped on the tree base.

Answer (score 8):

Looking for the tree by descriptions "mega bloks cartoon tree" and "mega bloks happy tree" I came across [this listing](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/dora-mega-bloks-blocks-44-pices-1725683738) with photos of the set. It's from a Dora the Explorer set with 44 pieces.

Comment: You are so-o-o awesome!   THANK YOU!!!